# If $u$ is *not* in row space of matrix $B$, then there exists a vector $x$ in the null space of $B$ such that $u\cdot x\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ be some matrix and $u$ be some (row) vector that is *not* in the row space of $B$.

True/False: There exists a (column) vector $x$ in the null space of $B$ such that $u\cdot x\neq 0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

This must surely be true, is there some reference for this? Thank you!

(Edit: SORRY I made some huge typos. They have now been corrected.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the row space and the null space of a matrix are orthogonal subspaces.

Hint 2: for any vector $u$ in my vector space, I can write $u=x+y$ where $x$ is in the row space of $B$ and $y$ is in the null space of $B$.

(Alternate approach) Hint 3: if $u\cdot x=0$ for all $x$ in the null space, where must $u$ live?

Comment: (Edit: SORRY I made some huge typos. They have now been corrected.)

Comment: Same hint applies.  Have you seen orthogonal decompositions?  I.e. $V=W\oplus W^\perp$?

Comment: From your hint, I have that any vector in the row space is orthogonal to any vector in the null space. However what I want to show is that any vector *not* in the row space is non-orthogonal to some vector in the null space. So I am not sure how your hint can help me. Thank you for the hint, and if you could elaborate.

Comment: @KennyLJ icurays1 hinted that any vector can be written as $\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}$ where $\mathbf{x}$ is in the rowspace and $\mathbf{y}$ is in the nullspace. If $\mathbf{u}$ is _not_ in the rowspace, then can $\mathbf{y}$ be $\mathbf{0}$ in the above decomposition? What happens then when you take $\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{y}$?

Comment: I see, so now if I take any vector $z$ in the null space of $B$, it would be true that $u\cdot z=(x+y)\cdot z=x\cdot z + y\cdot z=0+y\cdot z$ and since $y,z$ are both in the same null space, $y\cdot z\neq 0$. (Correct me if I'm wrong.) Thank you!